# Why does ASIO keep returning the same data

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Hi I am writing an online multiplayer game in C++ using SFML and ASIO for networking. I was sending data back and forth between server and client and the server was sending the correct data but the client keeps acting as if it has received the same data. I have deduced this error to the fact that ASIO is caching the data. Data is and needs to be sent back and forth each frame.
If I send: {"Hello"} as my first message no matter what is sent after the client only sees this
To read the data on the client I am using the following code

```
asio::read_until(socket, buffer, TRAILER);
str_data=asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data());
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the alleged problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal Ball engaged: You problem is likely
that you use a [Dynamic Buffer (V1 or V2)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer.html) concept. E.g. `asio::streambuf` or `asio::dynamic_string_buffer`/`asio::dynamic_vector_buffer`, usually by virtue of a member `vector` or `string` that is used with `asio::dynamic_buffer(m_vec_or_string)`.

Dynamic buffers should be **consumed**. For filling the contents one should `.prepare()`/`.commit()`, and after extracting content you should use `.consume()`.

The easiest way to achieve all these with `asio::streambuf` is - obviously - to attach a stream:

```
 asio::streambuf buf(/*optional_max_capacity*/);
 /*size_t len = */asio::read_until(socket_, buf, "\n");
```

Now you can attach a stream

```
 std::istream is(&buf);
```

All the usual stream operations work and wil automatically call the right buffer management functions as mentioned:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(is, line); // calls buf.consume(len) implicitly
```

For the other types of buffers you'll have to do the "math" yourself!

```
std::string buf;
auto        dynbuf = asio::dynamic_buffer(buf);

size_t len = asio::read_until(socket_, dynbuf, "\n");

process_data(buf.substr(0, len));
dynbuf.consume(len);
```

Or, worse, if you don't keep the dynamic buffer instance around, you'll have to manipulate the string itself:

```
std::string buf;
size_t len = asio::read_until(socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf), "\n");

process_data(buf.substr(0, len));
buf = buf.substr(len);
```

Needless to say, I suggest you use the simplest buffer type you need, and then use the highest abstraction (streambuf > dynamic buffer > raw container) to avoid these kinds of bugs.